# Fancybox minWidth setting forces width to be static

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

How can I get content widths to size up in Fancybox? I would have expected this to automatic as I only set minWidth, but it seems only the initial width, when you open the modal dialog remains static. I have set maxWidth, but that has no effect on the width whatsoever. I remove all the width settings, and the content shows up crammed up in a small width area. I am confused as to how to get this working correctly.

```
$('a.various').fancybox({
    scrolling:'no',
    minWidth:450,
    minHeight:450,
    openEffect:'none',
    closeEffect:'none',
    closeBtn:false
});
```

This gives me increasing heights, but widths stay static. I need the width to increase when let's say there is a larger image and such. I tried setting the minWidth property to 640, but that produce too much whitespace to the right of images that are smaller in width.

Comment: I also tried setting the inline container width and height via CSS, and that just gives me a height of 640px, and a way too slender of a width, where the content is completely cut off.

Comment: I've discovered that somehow fancybox is forcing the container of the inline content to be 100px. I can adjust height by manually setting it in the styling, but width cannot be adjusted.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure also to set the autoSize to true:

```
autoWidth : true,
```

You don't need the minWidth.

And the HTML you want the be displayed inside fancyBox also should have a specific given width.

Fx. if you want the content to be 300px in width, set the body to be 300px in width:

```
<body style="width: 300px;">
```

That's the way I do it. Hope it works :D

Comment: autoSize: true; is the same as: autoWidth: true; and autoHeight: true;

Using autoWidth or autoSize is your choice. They do the same